# How to slide owl-carousel on next prev hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to slide the owl-carousel when I hover on `next prev` button. But I can't find a solution on it. Can someone help me?

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop: true,
margin: 10,
responsiveClass: true,
responsive: {
   0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
 600: {
        items: 1,
        nav: false
      },
 1000: {
        items: 3,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        margin: 20
      }
  }
  })
});
$('.owl-prev, .owl-next').on('hover', function(){
$(this).click();
});
```

Comment: Your hover handler is not inside the document.ready event. -> owl-prev and owl-next won't be available here.... but even then... if both are created by the plugin you have to attach the event to an element which already there e.g body (event delegation)... $('body').on('hover', .'owl-prev, .owl-next', function (){...});

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is initializing the owl carousel on page load. What you can do is, initialize it on hover like this:

```js
$('.owl-prev, .owl-next').on('hover', function(){
   $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  responsiveClass: true,
  responsive: {
     0: {
          items: 1,
          nav: true
        },
   600: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false
        },
   1000: {
          items: 3,
          nav: true,
          loop: false,
          margin: 20
        }
    }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');

  $owl.owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 1,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 3,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        margin: 20
      }
    }
  });

  $('.owl-prev').on('hover', function() {
    $owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
  });
  $('.owl-next').on('hover', function() {
    $owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [300]);
  });
});
```

Maybe like this? Just with a quick look over the API. Hope it helps a bit. :)